# how to code- send connection/friend request in react native app

Tags: react-native

Functionality: Send a connection/friend request to another user of the same app built on react native

Can anyone please suggest how do I code this functionality

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make a social app. Rather than sending in-app notifications and friend requests , you should structure your app properly about how the requests flow will be processed via backend. That's how facebook , instagram does , they have their servers for each functionality and upon click of any request buttons in the app ,those api's are called and respective friend requests are sent to the user. So structure your code-architecture first. 
Do find the link below , it may help you 
[React native social app](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/build-a-social-app-with-react-native/lessons/introduction)